# zoom each image using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a main div under which i have three different div, each sub div contain image and text. i want to zoom image of that particular sub div to scale(1.1) whenever i hover on a that sub div.  for now when i hover on any sub div all the three images of all sub div are scaled.

html for my code is

```
<html>
<div class="main">

<div class="sub-div">
<img class="img" src="...">
<p>abc</p>
</div>

<div class="sub-div">
<img class="img" src="...">
<p>xyz</p>
</div>

<div class="sub-div">
<img class="img" src="...">
<p>abz</p>
</div>

</div>
```

and jquery is

```
$(".sub-div").each(function(){
   $(this).hover(function(){
   $('.img').css('transform','scale(1.1)');
   },function(){
   $('.img').css('transform','scale(1.0)');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely have to use Javascript, use the selector `this` :

```
$(".sub-div").hover(function(){
   $('.img',this).css('transform','scale(1.1)');
   },function(){
   $('.img',this).css('transform','scale(1.0)');
});
```

But you can do the same with CSS :

```
.sub-div:hover .img{
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Working JSFiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/26zdf038/

Comment: it still scales all the three images when i hover on any one sub div

Answer (score 1):

Why `jquery`? .simply do with css [`:hover`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiBl5fcoZfUAhUaTI8KHdFsCB8QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcssref%2Fsel_hover.asp&usg=AFQjCNGsp1Az0roCisrFWpUXDrnokPp2qw&sig2=0yGkQI1V164Jc30GxXTI_g)

```css
.sub-div img{
transition:all 0.2s ease-in;
transform:scale(1.0);
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
.sub-div:hover img{
transform:scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div class="main">

  <div class="sub-div">
    <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    <p>abc</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-div">
    <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    <p>xyz</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-div">
    <img class="img" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg">
    <p>abz</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: refering to the question he needs to scale the image, not the div.

Comment: @JurijJazdanov .i forget that.Thanks

Comment: but he wants to hover on div and scale image. You now scale the image only on image hover

Comment: now perfect, sry for being a jerk, I like when everything is perfect) +1 good job

Answer (score 1):

Try this It will help you,

```css
div:hover .picture{
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img class="picture" src="https://www.vetsure.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/puppies.jpg">
  </div>

  <div >
    <img class="picture" src="https://www.vetsure.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/puppies.jpg">
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <img class="picture" src="https://www.vetsure.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/puppies.jpg">   
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to loop with `each`. Just assign a hover event for `.sub-div`
2. Use `$(this)` to refer to the current object you interact with and [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) `img` inside of it.

```js
$(".sub-div").hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.img').css('transform','scale(1.1)');
},function(){
  $(this).find('.img').css('transform','scale(1.0)');
});
```

```css
.sub-div { 
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub-div">
    <img class="img" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">
    <p>abc</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-div">
    <img class="img" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">
    <p>xyz</p>
  </div>

  <div class="sub-div">
    <img class="img" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">
    <p>abz</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your selector for the image selects all the images, while you have to select only the child one:

```
$(".sub-div").each(function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.img').css('transform', 'scale(1.1)');
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.img').css('transform', 'scale(1.0)');
    });
});
```

However in that case I would recommend you to use CSS because of performance:

```
.sub-div img { transition: 0.3s ease }
.sub-div:hover img { transfrom: scale(1.1) }
```